# Issues with UPS's xml request is not valid xml

Tags: c#, xml

Not sure if anyone has had this issue with UPS's xml api request sample but I am trying to post an xml request to receive UPS rates. I am using their request example which I have posted below. However, this is not a valid xml document because it has more than one root tag, but if I post this to UPS it goes through fine.

What to do about this? Do I need to do some C# hacking to make this work? I am at a loss.

Why would UPS give an invalid example to use for their api? Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US"> <AccessLicenseNumber>Your Access License</AccessLicenseNumber> <UserId>Your User Id</UserId> <Password>Your Password</Password> </AccessRequest> <?xml version="1.0"?> <RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang="en-US"> <Request> <TransactionReference> <CustomerContext>Your Customer Context</CustomerContext> </TransactionReference> <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction> <RequestOption>Rate</RequestOption> </Request> <Shipment> <RateInformation> <NegotiatedRatesIndicator/> </RateInformation> <Shipper> <Name>Shipper Name</Name> <AttentionName>Shipper Attention Name</AttentionName> <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber> <FaxNumber>1234567890</FaxNumber> <ShipperNumber>Your Shipper Number</ShipperNumber> <Address> <AddressLine1>Address Line 1</AddressLine1> <City>City</City> <StateProvinceCode>StateProvinceCode</StateProvinceCode> <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode> <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode> </Address> </Shipper> <ShipTo> <CompanyName>Ship To Company Name</CompanyName> <AttentionName>Ship To Attention Name</AttentionName> <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber> <FaxNumber>1234567890</FaxNumber> <Address> <AddressLine1>Address Line 1</AddressLine1> <City>City</City> <StateProvinceCode>StateProvinceCode</StateProvinceCode> <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode> <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode> </Address> </ShipTo> <ShipFrom> <CompanyName>Ship From Company Name</CompanyName> <AttentionName>Ship From Attention Name</AttentionName> <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber> <FaxNumber>1234567890</FaxNumber> <Address><AddressLine1>Address Line 1</AddressLine1> <City>City</City> <StateProvinceCode>StateProvinceCode</StateProvinceCode> <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode> <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode> </Address> </ShipFrom> <Service> <Code>59</Code> <Description>2nd Day Air AM</Description> </Service> <Package> <PackagingType> <Code>02</Code> <Description>UPS Package</Description> </PackagingType> <PackageWeight> <UnitOfMeasurement> <Code>LBS</Code> </UnitOfMeasurement> <Weight>5</Weight> </PackageWeight> <Dimensions> <Length>10</Length> <Width>5</Width> <Height>7</Height> </Dimensions> </Package> </Shipment> </RatingServiceSelectionRequest>
```

XML File 1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <AccessLicenseNumber>Your Access License</AccessLicenseNumber>
  <UserId>Your User Id</UserId>
  <Password>Your Password</Password>
</AccessRequest>
```

Xml File 2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <Request>
    <TransactionReference>
      <CustomerContext>Your Customer Context</CustomerContext>
    </TransactionReference>
    <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction>
    <RequestOption>Rate</RequestOption>
  </Request>
  <Shipment>
    <RateInformation>
      <NegotiatedRatesIndicator/>
    </RateInformation>
    <Shipper>
      <Name>Shipper Name</Name>
      <AttentionName>Shipper Attention Name</AttentionName>
      <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
      <FaxNumber>1234567890</FaxNumber>
      <ShipperNumber>Your Shipper Number</ShipperNumber>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine1>Address Line 1</AddressLine1>
        <City>City</City>
        <StateProvinceCode>StateProvinceCode</StateProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </Shipper>
    <ShipTo>
      <CompanyName>Ship To Company Name</CompanyName>
      <AttentionName>Ship To Attention Name</AttentionName>
      <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
      <FaxNumber>1234567890</FaxNumber>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine1>Address Line 1</AddressLine1>
        <City>City</City>
        <StateProvinceCode>StateProvinceCode</StateProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </ShipTo>
    <ShipFrom>
      <CompanyName>Ship From Company Name</CompanyName>
      <AttentionName>Ship From Attention Name</AttentionName>
      <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
      <FaxNumber>1234567890</FaxNumber>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine1>Address Line 1</AddressLine1>
        <City>City</City>
        <StateProvinceCode>StateProvinceCode</StateProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </ShipFrom>
    <Service>
      <Code>59</Code>
      <Description>2nd Day Air AM</Description>
    </Service>
    <Package>
      <PackagingType>
        <Code>02</Code>
        <Description>UPS Package</Description>
      </PackagingType>
      <PackageWeight>
        <UnitOfMeasurement>
          <Code>LBS</Code>
        </UnitOfMeasurement>
        <Weight>5</Weight>
      </PackageWeight>
      <Dimensions>
        <Length>10</Length>
        <Width>5</Width>
        <Height>7</Height>
      </Dimensions>
    </Package>
  </Shipment>
</RatingServiceSelectionRequest>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Line ends make XML **much** easier to read

Comment: You have two xml files posted in the one line.

Comment: Yes I understand that but UPS has it were you have to post both together to get back a response without error.